# Using veritysetup with MTD on embedded Linux. mtd vs mtdblock

Tags: security, embedded, flash-memory

[Background]

I am working on an embedded Linux platform trying to setup dm-verity on NAND flash. I am using v2.3.0 of cryptsetup (part of soc vendor's package), and this is my first go at it. With `veritysetup` I have had success at creating the hash-tree and verifying it; where my data_device is an mtdblock which refers to the root filesystem partition (e.g. /dev/mtdblock8) and my hash_device points to a file path along another partition's mount path. However, this partition is not mounted and the file is not available until late in the boot sequence, so I am working to store the hash tree data directly to a memory block device so it is accessible during boot validation.

I have tried using the *same* mtdblock as the data_device, but supplying a hash-offset that is calculated using the number of data-blocks to verify * data-block-size. I have tried using an mtdblock for hash_device which is currently used for another partition's files (with or without an offset). And finally I have tried to use an empty mtdblock as my hash_device. This is just a random "leftover" raw partition which is not associated with anything. My preference is to use this empty block as it is roughly 2MB wasted space and could be useful for this purpose.

[Problem]

In the simplest form, my command looks something like: `veritysetup -v --debug format /dev/mtdblock8 /dev/mtdblockX` where X is some number. Each time, I get a generic I/O Error , and the --debug log says "Cannot write digest to hash device." This corresponds to an fwrite that fails in the verity_hash.c file of [cryptsetup](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/tree/main). Using a test program, I found that I cannot fwrite directly to /dev/mtdblockX but I can fwrite directly to /dev/mtdX (the *character device* associated with the mtdblock). **But**, providing the character device to veritysetup causes a failure! The tool does not accept character devices, it fails with an incompatible device error message, and in the code, the only accepted types of devices are Block devices and Regular files:

```
if (fstat(devfd, &st) < 0)
        r = -EINVAL;
    else if (!S_ISBLK(st.st_mode))
        r = S_ISREG(st.st_mode) ? -ENOTBLK : -EINVAL;
    if (r == -EINVAL) {
        log_err(cd, _("Device %s is not compatible."),
            device_path(device));
        close(devfd);
        return r;
    }
```

I think about modifying the code and recompiling for my platform but am hesitant to do so. I don't understand why veritysetup can't accept a character device? Linux seems to completely block any kind of write to a mtdblock device but permits it to the mtd device. To add to my confusion, I have found numerous examples online of people having apparent success referring to an /dev/mtdblock device as data_devices and hash_devices. I have also posted [this question](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/issues/771) in the cryptsetup gitlab issues section.